# Output time and date in the format: 2018-01-26 15:51.159753

Tags: c++

I am trying to find a solution on outputting current date and time (with milliseconds) in the following format: **2018-01-26 15:51:02.159753**

What I have right now (working) is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   // current date/time based on current system
   time_t now = time(0);

   // convert now to string form
   char* dt = ctime(&now);

   cout << "The local date and time is: " << dt << endl;

   // convert now to tm struct for UTC
   tm *gmtm = gmtime(&now);
   dt = asctime(gmtm);
   cout << "The UTC date and time is:"<< dt << endl;
}
```

I have although not found any way to remake this in order to output the date and time in my desired format. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: @kometen Unfortunately this answer doesn't deal with fractional seconds, which it turns out that are so important to the question that the OP isn't satisfied with my C++11 solution :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you'll want to use [`tm`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) from `localtime` which should probably be initialized like this:

```
const auto buz = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
const auto baz = chrono::floor<chrono::seconds>(buz);
const auto bar = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::time_point(baz));
const auto foo = localtime(&bar);
```

You can then use that with [`put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time):

```
cout << put_time(foo, "%F %T.") << (buz - baz).count() << endl;
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff7807cf6090a381)

Comment: `foo` is already a pointer so no `&` needed - `put_time(foo, "%F %T")`. Also the format needs some tweaking for the seconds decimal part `2018-01-26 15:27:09` - try at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a8f809e99bd3a5a. But the seconds are in int in the `tm` anyway

Comment: Mabye `auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now(); bar = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);` and use rest of now tor the nanoseconds :) Or maybe the https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: @A.A I am a huge fan of Howard Hinnant's date class. But here I think that we can make do.

Comment: `chrono::floor()` is C++17

Comment: @A.A True... and since we're in 2018 that seems appropriate, no? Though less clear, prior to that you could have used: `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>`

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Just one thing, I will use this with a SDK that does not even compile with C++11 so even though we're in 2018 and I am all up using C++17 it will not work :/ Shall I replace const auto baz = chrono::floor<chrono::seconds>(buz); with std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>?

Comment: @JJJones Unfortunately you *need* `chrono` to get higher precision, and it's only available on C++11. [The C Time Libraries](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c#Types) only support times as integers. So without C++11 you're looking for something more than the standard library, or you're going to have to give up fractional time.